# Maven gives org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar:org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream

Tags: maven, java-8, maven-3

My maven was running perfectly, suddenly it stops working for my projects.

Here are my settings,
Maven :- apache-maven-3.5.0
Java :- 1.8_77

I am getting below exception,

```
"
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar (attach-sources) on project audit_history_listener_service: Execution attach-sources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar: org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/ssoni27/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-source-plugin/3.0.1/maven-source-plugin-3.0.1.jar "
```

I have used other Maven version too like 5.2 and 3.3.9 but all the time it gives me the same error. I also clear my local repo which is under my .m2 director but no luck.

Please let me know how do I resolve it?

Here is full exception,

```
> [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Reactor Summary: [INFO]  [INFO] audit_history_listener_top
> ......................... SUCCESS [  1.743 s] [INFO]
> audit_history_listener_service ..................... FAILURE [  4.799
> s] [INFO] AuditHistoryListenerWAR ............................ SKIPPED
> [INFO] AuditHistoryListenerEAR ............................ SKIPPED
> [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 6.934 s [INFO] Finished at:
> 2017-10-27T16:38:44-07:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 54M/582M [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar
> (attach-sources) on project audit_history_listener_service: Execution
> attach-sources of goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar failed: A
> required class was missing while executing
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar:
> org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream [ERROR]
> ----------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1 [ERROR]
> strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
> [ERROR] urls[0] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-source-plugin/3.0.1/maven-source-plugin-3.0.1.jar
> [ERROR] urls[1] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
> [ERROR] urls[2] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
> [ERROR] urls[3] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.7/aether-util-1.7.jar
> [ERROR] urls[4] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
> [ERROR] urls[5] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.6/plexus-component-annotations-1.6.jar
> [ERROR] urls[6] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
> [ERROR] urls[7] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
> [ERROR] urls[8] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/3.1.1/maven-archiver-3.1.1.jar
> [ERROR] urls[9] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.0.1/maven-shared-utils-3.0.1.jar
> [ERROR] urls[10] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.5/commons-io-2.5.jar
> [ERROR] urls[11] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/3.4/plexus-archiver-3.4.jar
> [ERROR] urls[12] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.7.1/plexus-io-2.7.1.jar
> [ERROR] urls[13] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.11/commons-compress-1.11.jar
> [ERROR] urls[14] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/iq80/snappy/snappy/0.4/snappy-0.4.jar
> [ERROR] urls[15] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.5/xz-1.5.jar
> [ERROR] urls[16] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.24/plexus-utils-3.0.24.jar
> [ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1 [ERROR] import: Entry[import 
> from realm
> ClassRealm[project>com.americanexpress.mobile.wallet.audithistorylistener:audit_history_listener_top:2.10-SNAPSHOT,
> parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]] [ERROR]  [ERROR]
> ----------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] : org.apache.commons.io.output.DeferredFileOutputStream [ERROR] -> [Help
> 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
> execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar
> (attach-sources) on project audit_history_listener_service: Execution
> attach-sources of goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar failed: A
> required class was missing while executing
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar:
> org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream
> ----------------------------------------------------- realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1 strategy =
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy urls[0] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-source-plugin/3.0.1/maven-source-plugin-3.0.1.jar
> urls[1] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
> urls[2] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
> urls[3] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.7/aether-util-1.7.jar
> urls[4] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
> urls[5] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.6/plexus-component-annotations-1.6.jar
> urls[6] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
> urls[7] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
> urls[8] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/3.1.1/maven-archiver-3.1.1.jar
> urls[9] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.0.1/maven-shared-utils-3.0.1.jar
> urls[10] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.5/commons-io-2.5.jar
> urls[11] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/3.4/plexus-archiver-3.4.jar
> urls[12] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.7.1/plexus-io-2.7.1.jar
> urls[13] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.11/commons-compress-1.11.jar
> urls[14] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/iq80/snappy/snappy/0.4/snappy-0.4.jar
> urls[15] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.5/xz-1.5.jar
> urls[16] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.24/plexus-utils-3.0.24.jar
> Number of foreign imports: 1 import: Entry[import  from realm
> ClassRealm[project>com.americanexpress.mobile.wallet.audithistorylistener:audit_history_listener_top:2.10-SNAPSHOT,
> parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
> 
> -----------------------------------------------------
> 
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
> (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
> (Launcher.java:289)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
> (Launcher.java:415)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356) Caused by:
> org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution
> attach-sources of goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar failed: A
> required class was missing while executing
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar:
> org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream
> ----------------------------------------------------- realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1 strategy =
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy urls[0] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-source-plugin/3.0.1/maven-source-plugin-3.0.1.jar
> urls[1] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
> urls[2] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
> urls[3] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.7/aether-util-1.7.jar
> urls[4] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
> urls[5] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.6/plexus-component-annotations-1.6.jar
> urls[6] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
> urls[7] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
> urls[8] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/3.1.1/maven-archiver-3.1.1.jar
> urls[9] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.0.1/maven-shared-utils-3.0.1.jar
> urls[10] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.5/commons-io-2.5.jar
> urls[11] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/3.4/plexus-archiver-3.4.jar
> urls[12] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.7.1/plexus-io-2.7.1.jar
> urls[13] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.11/commons-compress-1.11.jar
> urls[14] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/iq80/snappy/snappy/0.4/snappy-0.4.jar
> urls[15] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.5/xz-1.5.jar
> urls[16] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.24/plexus-utils-3.0.24.jar
> Number of foreign imports: 1 import: Entry[import  from realm
> ClassRealm[project>com.americanexpress.mobile.wallet.audithistorylistener:audit_history_listener_top:2.10-SNAPSHOT,
> parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
> 
> -----------------------------------------------------
> 
>     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:168)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
> (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
> (Launcher.java:289)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
> (Launcher.java:415)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356) Caused by:
> org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: A required class was
> missing while executing
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:jar:
> org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream
> ----------------------------------------------------- realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1 strategy =
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy urls[0] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-source-plugin/3.0.1/maven-source-plugin-3.0.1.jar
> urls[1] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
> urls[2] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
> urls[3] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.7/aether-util-1.7.jar
> urls[4] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
> urls[5] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.6/plexus-component-annotations-1.6.jar
> urls[6] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
> urls[7] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
> urls[8] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/3.1.1/maven-archiver-3.1.1.jar
> urls[9] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.0.1/maven-shared-utils-3.0.1.jar
> urls[10] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.5/commons-io-2.5.jar
> urls[11] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/3.4/plexus-archiver-3.4.jar
> urls[12] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.7.1/plexus-io-2.7.1.jar
> urls[13] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.11/commons-compress-1.11.jar
> urls[14] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/iq80/snappy/snappy/0.4/snappy-0.4.jar
> urls[15] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.5/xz-1.5.jar
> urls[16] =
> file:/Users/shailendra/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.24/plexus-utils-3.0.24.jar
> Number of foreign imports: 1 import: Entry[import  from realm
> ClassRealm[project>com.americanexpress.mobile.wallet.audithistorylistener:audit_history_listener_top:2.10-SNAPSHOT,
> parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
> 
> -----------------------------------------------------
> 
>     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:166)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
> (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
> (Launcher.java:289)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
> (Launcher.java:415)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.ResourceFactory.createResource
> (ResourceFactory.java:56)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.PlexusIoFileResourceCollection.addResourcesJava7
> (PlexusIoFileResourceCollection.java:198)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.PlexusIoFileResourceCollection.getResources
> (PlexusIoFileResourceCollection.java:288)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext (AbstractArchiver.java:512)
>     at org.apache.maven.plugins.source.AbstractSourceJarMojo.packageSources
> (AbstractSourceJarMojo.java:287)
>     at org.apache.maven.plugins.source.AbstractSourceJarMojo.packageSources
> (AbstractSourceJarMojo.java:253)
>     at org.apache.maven.plugins.source.AbstractSourceJarMojo.execute (AbstractSourceJarMojo.java:216)
>     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
> (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
> (Launcher.java:289)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
> (Launcher.java:415)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.apache.commons.io.output.DeferredFileOutputStream
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass
> (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass
> (ClassRealm.java:271)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.ResourceFactory.createResource
> (ResourceFactory.java:56)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.PlexusIoFileResourceCollection.addResourcesJava7
> (PlexusIoFileResourceCollection.java:198)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.PlexusIoFileResourceCollection.getResources
> (PlexusIoFileResourceCollection.java:288)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext (AbstractArchiver.java:512)
>     at org.apache.maven.plugins.source.AbstractSourceJarMojo.packageSources
> (AbstractSourceJarMojo.java:287)
>     at org.apache.maven.plugins.source.AbstractSourceJarMojo.packageSources
> (AbstractSourceJarMojo.java:253)
>     at org.apache.maven.plugins.source.AbstractSourceJarMojo.execute (AbstractSourceJarMojo.java:216)
>     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
> (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
> (Launcher.java:289)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
> (Launcher.java:415)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356) [ERROR]  [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information
> about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following
> articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
> [ERROR]  [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the
> build with the command [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf
> :audit_history_listener_service
```

Comment: Please show your full pom file and the full log output and furthermore how have you called Maven? What does `mvn --version` show ?

Comment: Below is output, Also I was trying on Maven 3.3.9, 5.0 and 5.2 as well. 
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T12:39:06-07:00)
Maven home: /Users/ssoni27/Shailendra/Softwares/apache-maven-3.5.0
Java version: 1.8.0_77, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.12.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Comment: Run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` add results to question. Add your pom in question with the dependency suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.

Be sure you do not run on Java9.

Comment: No, it is not working. It gives the same error. Does maven refer any other cache files rather than .m2 director?

Comment: @ShailendraSoni can you edit some more maven log in your question?

Comment: @ShailendraSoni You claim using java8. Do log files tell the same?

Comment: Yes. I have only java8.

Comment: attached full exceptions for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

We have our own private repository where this common-io file is corrupted hence Maven source plugin is giving the error. I replaced with correct version in my local repository and start working again. 
So the issue is with the local repo, just replacing common-io jar with the one we get in apache-maven/lib  solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple folder in my ~/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io. I deleted all of them and ran the build again and it solved my problem.